# Jackson + Jersey not serializing Date properly

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I'm working on a REST API using Jersey + Jackson, but I'm having problems with date serializing.

You see, I configured a `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` as such:

```java
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {

    public static final ObjectMapper mapper;

    static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                // DateUtils.ISO_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtils.ISO_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())) 
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    public JacksonProvider() {
        super();
        setMapper(mapper);
    }
}
```

And yet it is serializing dates in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, without even time info!

Before you ask:

- Jersey version: `2.32`
- Jackson version: `2.7.2`
- Yes, I know those versions are kinda old, this is a legacy project I'm trying to upgrade. It was still using some SOAP endpoints when I started, and didn't even use Maven for dependencies...
- Yes, I searched other questions before asking, and I tried their solutions to no avail.
- Yes, my `pom.xml` is correctly configured.
- Yes, my dependencies are correct, none are missing or wrong, since EVERYTHING ELSE is working, except date serialization...
- Yes, I setup a JUnit test to see if my `ObjectMapper` is setup correctly, and it is, its both reading AND writing dates on the expected format.
- Yes, I'm aware of the `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMP` bit, its not it, I tried commenting that line.
- Yes, I made tests to guarantee that Jersey is ACTUALLY using that provider.
- Yes, the other `ObjectMapper` configurations are working as expected, only the `DateFormat` seems to be ignored by Jackson.
- Yes, I tried using other formats, and Jackson just ignores them as well.
- Yes, I tried the `@JsonFormat` annotation, and it works, but that annotation is to setup field-specific formats, what I want is a GLOBAL date format for Jackson to use.
- Yes, I tried using a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>` and it ALSO doesn't work.
- Yes, I tried a quick fix to test using Gson instead of Jackson, and it worked like a charm, but all other parts of the project are using Jackson already, switching would be... time consuming.
- Yes, there are multiple ways I know that I could implement to... "work around" that issue, but I don't want to "work around" it, I want to FIX it.

Keep it in mind: My objective here is to **setup a global Date format for Jackson to use in serialization/deserialization in a *CLEAN, EASY* way**

Any help is welcome.

## Update

As requested, here's some more code:

### `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- package info here -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <jersey.version>2.32</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <webXml>src/web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/web</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Enable SOAP (because it still has some leftover SOAP endpoints) -->
        <!-- API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### `Application.java`

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application() {
//        Register Jackson provider
        register(JacksonProvider.class);
//        Register endpoint
        register(ExampleEndpoint.class);
//        More registrations here...
    }
}
```

### `ExampleEndpoint.java`

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTimestamp() {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

            response.put("current_timestamp", new Date());

            return Response.ok(response).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().entity(e).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you tried all those things and it still doesn't work, your next step is to probably provide an [mre] as no one will be able to solve the problem with just the code you provided. All quesses will be the ones you've tried.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your provider is the one being used?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yes, I tested it, Jersey is using the provider I created, since alterations in the `ObjectMapper` serialization configurations are reflected on the resulting json from API requests. The issue here is that Jackson is seemingly "ignoring" my date format configuration, and ONLY that configuration.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha well, it seems I'll have to work around that issue for now. The time it will take to setup an example project on github is the time it will take to switch to Gson...

Comment: Added more code samples, to see if it helps, but all of it is just your vanilla jersey + jackson rest api code, nothing too fancy.

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/429116f0049cea2423fc4580112708f4). Versions used were 2.32. Even if I remove the Jackson dependency I used and just use yours.

Comment: The plot thickens: I literally just redeployed the application, without even changing a single line of code, and it started working.

Then (again without any changes) I redeployed the code again, and it stopped working.

What in tarnation is happening...

Comment: What server are you using? And in both cases, your provider is always the one being used, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since date formatting works as expected in tests but not when the app is deployed, you need to verify the actual provider version used when your app is deployed.

I'm guessing (until you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you have **two** provider jars in your classpath, one supplied by your application server (i.e. in Glassfish modules directory) and one packaged in your app (or in lib/ext directory). This could explain the weird behavior stated in your comment:

> The plot thickens: I literally just redeployed the application, without even changing a single line of code, and it started working. Then (again without any changes) I redeployed the code again, and it stopped working.

It could be classpath *order* being changed between deployments and your app uses the other provider version.

If this is the case, a working approach would be:

1. Verify the version provided by your application server
2. Use that exact version in your pom.xml with `provided` scope (so you will always use the AS provided implementation

NB: This approach will bind your app to the AS.